# The function spaces $C^1([0,1]\times [0,1],\mathbb{R})$, $C^1([0,1],C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R}))$ and $C^0([0,1],C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}))$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

I wanted to know how different these three function spaces are: $C^1([0,1]\times [0,1],\mathbb{R})$, $C^1([0,1],C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R}))$ and $C^0([0,1],C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}))$, and whether there are some nice inclusion relations among them. ( For example, one is contained in another, or the intersection of two is contained in the third.)

Here by $C^1([0,1],C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R}))$, I mean differentiable functions from $[0,1]$ to the Banach space $C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ with continuous derivative. The meaning of $C^0([0,1],C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}))$ is similar, where we use $C^1$ norm on $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

I am also interested in the $C^k$ analogue of the above question.

*Remark*: The $C^0$ case is easy: $C^0([0,1]\times[0,1],\mathbb{R})=C^0([0,1],C^0([0,1],\mathbb{R}))$ since continuous functions $[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ are uniformly continuous.

If there is a standard result concerning this question, could anybody give me the reference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Theorem B in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06095.pdf) paper or Theorem A of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.6510.pdf) one may be of interest to you. But I'm sure an elementary proof is possible in this scenario also.

Comment: @s.harp Thank you for your comment! And sorry for late reply. In fact I was previously thinking about $C^\infty(\cdot,C\infty(\dot,))$ things in more general situations and wanted to know if a naive attempt was hopeful, so I asked that. It seems the references you provided could really help me with that, although I did make it in another way…